# What does the no of nodes represent in a Convolution Layer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

What does the number 16 (no. of outputs) represent in this Convo layer?

```
 layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
```

Comment: Hi @ShushilKgadka, welcome to the site. [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64281/14675) you have some context on the concept of "channels" in a convolutional layer.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have **16 filters** of **3x3 kernels**. If you check the number of trainable parameters, you have : **16** filters x **9** parameters per kernel x **3** channels (for RGB images) + **16** biaises (one per filter) = **448 trainable parameters**

Comment: So the software knows that both dimensions are $3$ pixels if you only specify one number? I feel like I’ve always specified both dimensions.

Comment: If you mean the size of the kernel yes , it does understand its a 3 X 3 kernel in case of 1 channel image and 3 x 3 x n  in a n channel image.